# Javascript Covert object value in array from string to number

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to convert this

```
const data = [
 {
   date: "2020-01",
   pageviews: "1548"
 },
 {
   date: "2020-01",
   pageviews: "2000"
 },
]
```

to

```
const data = [
 {
   date: "2020-01",
   pageviews: 1548
 },
 {
   date: "2020-01",
   pageviews: 2000
 },
]
```

but I can't find the a way.
I want to use those data to [Rechart](https://recharts.org/en-US) and the pageviews need to be numbers not strings
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

### Solution

You can use forEach to loop over your array.
At each entry parse your pageviews to an int with `parseInt()`

```js
const data = [
 {
   date: "2020-01",
   pageviews: "1548"
 },
 {
   date: "2020-01",
   pageviews: "2000"
 },
]

console.log(data);

data.forEach((val) => {
  val.pageviews = parseInt(val.pageviews);
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: You're welcome :) if you think this was helpful you can mark this as accepted.

Comment: Using `.map()` instead of `.forEach()` to mutate the elements' properties is pretty weird.

Comment: True first I thought I create a new array but I didn't, have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
  const data = [
 {
   date: "2020-01",
   pageviews: "1548"
 },
 {
   date: "2020-01",
   pageviews: "2000"
 },
]

 data.forEach(item => {
  item.pageviews = parseInt(item.pageviews)
  return item
 })
 
 console.log(data)
</script>
```

You can use the parseInt function of JavaScript to convert your String to a Number.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to alter the original array, you can use `Array#map` with spread syntax.

```js
const data = [
 {
   date: "2020-01",
   pageviews: "1548"
 },
 {
   date: "2020-01",
   pageviews: "2000"
 },
]
const res = data.map(({pageviews, ...rest})=>({...rest, pageviews: +pageviews}));
console.log(res);
```